# React-Redux connect: Use mapStatetoProps to inject only component part of store

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga

[React-Redux] Issue.

I'd like to have reusable encapsulated components to be used in any app, or in any level of the app's store.

When it comes to use 'mapStatetoProps' then making the component container (injecting the state into the component as props), you always receive the whole store. This might be a pain if you want to reuse components dynamically or in other projects.

The thing is if you use the same store entry but you want to use the same component as encapsulated module they will be sharing the same data.

And also, when you are encapsulating components and you reuse them and they are deep nested in the store, you will end up needing to know where they are.

A possible ugly solution would be to implement a script going through the state inside the mapStateToProps till it finds the key matching certain name. The issue here would be to make sure the state field you want to use is unique.

I'll be more than happy to know any proper solution to this problem in an elegant way.

Or maybe we are just thinking the wrong way when talking about react-redux-sagas apps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to make the components totally independent from state and hierarchy within the app.

Basically, each component must expose a method to set the path within the state. Then you have to initialize it when either when you import it before using it. You could also implement it in another way so you receive it inline as a prop.

It makes uses of reselect to establish the selection.

Each component knows the name of its key in the state.

The root component will import other components and it will call the setPath method of each one passing the root component path.

Then each component will call the setPath of each subcomponent passing their own location in the state. "Each parent will init their children"

So each component will set a path in the store based on the naming "parent path + local path (component key name in the store)".

This way you would be defining a nested routing with 'createSelector' method from reselect, like this: ['rootKey','subComponent1Key','subsubComponent1Key].

With this, you have the store isolation completed. Redux actions will just change the bit needed so yo have this part also covered by the framework.

It worked like a charm for me, please let me know if its good before I mark it as good.

Comment: Please note that, this would work if your component unique in the page, as import is singleton, if you try to setPath of a duplicated component it will affect the same module. In case you need to have same container in several places in the page then u will need to find another solution, or a way to isolate the logic in a factory so its not singleton any longer

Answer (score 3):

For the sake of the example, I'll be talking about a reusable editor component, that edits documents and submits them to server.

In the code that is using the editor, I give each editor a unique id. E.g.

```
const Comment = (props) => {
  return <div>
    <h3>Add new comment</h3>
    <Editor editorId={`new-comment-${props.commentId}`} />
  </div>
}
```

In the redux state, I have one subreducer editor with objects keyed by the editorId, so the redux state is something like:

```
{
  otherStuff: {...},
  editor: {
    "new-comment-123": { isActive: true, text: "Hello there" },
    "new-comment-456": { isActive: false, text: "" },
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```

Then in Editor `mapStateToProps` I use selectors to get the data for the correct instance:

```
const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {
  return {
    isActive: selectors.isActive(state, ownProps.editorId),
    text: selectors.text(state, ownProps.editorId)
  }
}
```

The selectors are built in [reselect](https://github.com/reactjs/reselect) style, either manually or by actually using reselect. Example:

```
// Manual code
export const getEditor = (state, editorId) => state.editor[editorId] || {};
export const isActive = (state, editorId) => getEditor(state, editorId).
export const text = (state, editorId) => getEditor(state, editorId).text;

// Same in reselect
import { createSelector } from 'reselect'

export const getEditor = (state, editorId) => state.editor[editorId] || {};
export const isActive = createSelector([getEditor], (editorData) => editorData.isActive);
export const text = createSelector([getEditor], (editorData) => editorData.text);
```

If you want to extend this to be used in multiple apps, you need to export your component, reducer and sagas. For a working example, check out https://github.com/woltapp/redux-autoloader or even http://redux-form.com

Comment: Could you please explain a bit further how u deal with reselect? Are u needed to specify the root path as a selector in very place where u use the component or similar?

Comment: I added an example of selectors, they are really useful in all kinds of apps: you have defined in exactly one place how a certain type of data is retrieved from redux, makes refactoring the redux state much easier. The same selector is of course used in many `mapStateToProps` functions.

Comment: This is almost a valid solution, but still not what I was looking for, the thing is that I'm looking for a way, to drop a component at any level and connect it to the parent state with reselect, then the parent will be connected to its parent and so on, so it's like a reverse cascade of connections, so you can put anything wherever u want.

Comment: I guess you could do that, but that would mean you have deeply nested structures in your redux state. This is not recommended, redux recommends that you normalize state and refer to nested objects by id, keeping their data in another part of the state. I've personally found this to be a great practice that leads to simpler code and less out of sync bugs. Check out http://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your concern correctly, you could implement `mapStateToProps` as if it receives the part of state you need and call it, say, `mapStateToYourComponentProps`, and in actual `mapStateToProps` you just call `mapStateToYourComponentProps` and pass it appropriate part of state

Comment: The thing is I don't want to know what is the appropriate part of the state. This is the part we went to "automate"

Answer (score 0):

If you have some free time, try the npm package redux-livequery (https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-livequery) I just wrote recently.

There is another way to manage your active list.

```
    let selector0 = (state) => state.task.isComplete;
    let selector1 = (state) => state.task.taskList;
    this.unsub2 = rxQueryBasedOnObjectKeys([selector0, selector1], ['isActive', 'task'], (completeTaskList) => {
        // equal SQL =>
        // select * from isActive LEFT JOIN taskList on isActive.child_key == taskList.child_key
        console.log("got latest completeTaskList", completeTaskList);
        // you can do whatever you want here
        // ex: filter, reduce, map

        this.setState({ completeTaskList });
    }, 0);
```

In the reducer:

```
    case "MARK_ACTIVE_TASK": {
        let { id } = action.meta;
        return update(state, { isActive: { [id]: { $set: { active: Date.now() } } } });
    }
    case "UNMARK_ACTIVE_TASK": {
        let { id } = action.meta;
        return update(state, { isActive: { $apply: function (x) { let y = Object.assign({}, x); delete y[id]; return y; } } });
    }
```

It lets you have simpler reducer. In addition, there is no more nested selector function or filter which is really expensive operation. Putting your all logic in the same place would be great.

And it can do even more complexity operation like how to get complete and active list.

```
    let selector0 = (state) => state.task.isComplete;
    let selector1 = (state) => state.task.isActive;
    let selector2 = (state) => state.task.taskList;
    this.unsub3 = rxQueryInnerJoin([selector0, selector1, selector2], ['isComplete', 'isActive', 'task'], (completeAndActiveTaskList) => {
        // equal SQL =>
        // select * from isComplete INNER JOIN isActive on isComplete.child_key == isActive.child_key
        //                          INNER JOIN taskList on isActive.child_key == taskList.child_key
        console.log("got latest completeAndActiveTaskList", completeAndActiveTaskList);
        // you can do whatever you want here
        // ex: filter, reduce, map

        this.setState({ completeAndActiveTaskList });
    }, 0);
```

If you would like to get complete or active list, it's also easy to get.
The more example, please refer to the sample code => https://github.com/jeffnian88/redux-livequery-todos-example